# Soma acumulada de dados em nova coluna python

Tags: python, loop, dataframe, columns

Ola pessoal eu tenho um dataframe com dados de entrada e saida por dia
a minha necessidade e adicionar a essa dataframe uam coluna cumulativa
são entradas e saidas diarias então no excel eu teria o seguinte codigo

coluna A: dados de entrada e saida
coluna B = dado da coluna A de hoje + dado da coluna B de ontem

tendo a seguinte saida

| # | A | B(formula) | B(saida) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | =A1+B0 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 | =A2+B1 | 30 |
| 3 | -5 | =A3+B2 | 25 |
| 4 | -10 | =A4+B3 | 15 |
| 5 | 20 | =A5+B4 | 35 |

para isso a partir do cabeçalho do meu data frame eu criei um dicionario com indices começando em 1

```
dict={1:produto1, 2:produto2, 3:produto3}
```

e entao uma estrutura de repetição que criaria uma coluna nova para cada iten do meu dicionario concatenado com 'acc'

```
tcolunas = DataFrame.columns()
tcolunas = DataFrame.tolist()

conts = 1
for n in t colunas:
      x = str(tcolunas[conts-1]) + ' acc'
      DataFrame[x] = (DataFrame[dict[conts]] + DataFrame[x].shif(1))
      conts = conts + 1
```

A saida me fornece a soma por uma linha porem zerando logo em seguida, dessa maneira:

| entradas/saidas | acc |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 99 | 99 |
| 30 | 129 |
| 0 | 30 |
| 0 | 0 |

Acredito que o programa não consiga iterar dentro da mesma coluna sobre ela propria
teriam alguma solução para isso ?

Comment: corrigindo 

```
tcolunas = DataFrame.columns()
tcolunas = tcolunas.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o que precisa é o método `cumsum()`

Veja o exemplo:

### Criando DataFrame

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10, 20, -5, -10, 20]})

>>> df
    A
0  10
1  20
2  -5
3 -10
4  20
```

### Criando coluna com soma acumulada

```
>>> df["B"] = df["A"].cumsum()

>>> df
    A   B
0  10  10
1  20  30
2  -5  25
3 -10  15
4  20  35
>>>
```

Espero que ajude